# override/redeclare a class with generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, three.js, decorator, wrapper

currently i am working on a project using three js and typescript. I have found out that for grouping purposes the [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Group#api/en/objects/Group) class is recommended. Unfortunately the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/three/src/objects/Group.d.ts) of `Group` dont come with a generic like this

```
meshGroup = new Group<Mesh>()
```

of where the `meshGroup.children` property only consists of [Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Mesh#api/en/objects/Mesh)

i tried this

```
declare class MeshGroup extends Group {
  children: Mesh[]
  add(...object: Mesh[]): this
}

meshGroup = new MeshGroup()
```

but got this console error

```
_classes_MeshGroup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__.MeshGroup is not a constructor
```

I looked up if theres an easy way to implement such simple wrapper in typescript but with no success.

My other solution would be to implement an typed array of

```
meshGroup: Mesh[] = []
```

and keep it in sync with the class to handle the types but it adds another layer of handling the sync.

Since i am not a pro at using typescript, is there a quick type definition trick to implement this "wrapper"-Definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Its also kinda possible extending the `Group` class with a more type-safer class and calling the parent functions ([decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator)):

```
import { Group } from 'three'
import { Object3D } from 'three/src/core/Object3D'

export default class TypedGroup<T extends Object3D = Object3D> extends Group {
  children: T[] = []

  add(...object: T[]) {
    return super.add(...object)
  }

  remove(...object: T[]): this {
    return super.remove(...object)
  }

  attach(object: T): this {
    return super.attach(object)
  }

  getObjectById(id: number): T | undefined {
    return super.getObjectById(id) as T | undefined
  }

  getObjectByName(name: string): T | undefined {
    return super.getObjectByName(name) as T | undefined
  }

  getObjectByProperty(name: string, value: string): T | undefined {
    return super.getObjectByProperty(name, value) as T | undefined
  }
}
```

**my initial/old answer**

Thanks for the answer **[@Marquizzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699923/12365729)**!

That defenitely could be a solution. Currently i came up with another way with overriding the package via [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) and edit the `Group.d.ts` file like this:

```
export class Group<T extends Object3D = Object3D> extends Object3D {
    constructor();
    type: 'Group';
    readonly isGroup: true;
    children: T[];
    add(...object: T[]): this;
    remove(...object: T[]): this;
    attach(object: T): this;
    getObjectById(id: number): T | undefined;
    getObjectByName(name: string): T | undefined;
    getObjectByProperty(name: string, value: string): T | undefined;
}
```

In addition to your answer i also get type-safety on the methods which was important to me too!

I dont know if this fits the best for my needs in the future but currently this solves my type-addiction :D

Answer (score 0):

When you call `group.children` you get an array `Object3D[]` [as per the definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/85c07a9c3a998368ad51fc460bff628c90b49806/types/three/src/core/Object3D.d.ts#L51). This is because `Group` could have other `Group, Sprite, Line, Point, Mesh, etc.` inside it, so it defaults to the generic `Object3D`. However, if you're sure it will only contain `Mesh`es, you could simply nudge it with:

```ts
const group: THREE.Group = new THREE.Group();
const children = group.children as THREE.Mesh[];

// Now we can access Mesh attributes, like
const mat = children[0].material;
```